# Find mixed types in Pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas

Ever so often I get this warning when parsing data files:

```
WARNING:py.warnings:/usr/local/python3/miniconda/lib/python3.4/site-
packages/pandas-0.16.0_12_gdcc7431-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas
/io/parsers.py:1164: DtypeWarning: Columns (0,2,14,20) have mixed types. 
Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
          data = self._reader.read(nrows)
```

But if the data is large (I have 50k rows), how can I find WHERE in the data the change of dtype occurs?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're after, but it's easy enough to find the rows which contain elements which don't share the type of the first row.  For example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": np.arange(500), "B": np.arange(500.0)})
>>> df.loc[321, "A"] = "Fred"
>>> df.loc[325, "B"] = True
>>> weird = (df.applymap(type) != df.iloc[0].apply(type)).any(axis=1)
>>> df[weird]
        A     B
321  Fred   321
325   325  True
```

Answer (score 12):

This approach uses [`pandas.api.types.infer_dtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.api.types.infer_dtype.html) to find the columns which have mixed dtypes. It was tested with Pandas 1 under Python 3.8.

Note that this answer has multiple uses of [assignment expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#syntax-and-semantics) which work only with Python 3.8 or newer. It can however trivially be modified to not use them.

```py
if mixed_dtypes := {c: dtype for c in df.columns if (dtype := pd.api.types.infer_dtype(df[c])).startswith("mixed")}:
    raise TypeError(f"Dataframe has one more mixed dtypes: {mixed_dtypes}")
```

This approach doesn't however find a row with the changed dtype.

Answer (score 11):

In addition to DSM's answer, with a many-column dataframe it can be helpful to find the columns that change type like so:

```
for col in df.columns:
    weird = (df[[col]].applymap(type) != df[[col]].iloc[0].apply(type)).any(axis=1)
    if len(df[weird]) > 0:
        print(col)
```

Answer (score 2):

Create sample data with a column that has 2 data types

```
import seaborn
iris = seaborn.load_dataset("iris")
# Change one row to another type
iris.loc[0,"sepal_length"] = iris.loc[0,"sepal_length"].astype(str)
```

When columns use more than one type, print the column name and the types used:

```
for col in iris.columns:
    unique_types = iris[col].apply(type).unique()
    if len(unique_types) > 1:
        print(col, unique_types)
```

To fix the column types you can:

- use `df[col] = df[col].astype(str)` to change the data type.
- or if the data frame was read from a csv file define the  ̀dtype` argument in a dictionary of columns.

Answer (score 1):

The DataGlitch package identifies the different dtypes in your column and returns a subset for each type.

```
pip install DataGlitch

from DataGlitch.dtype_detector import find_numeric

numeric, ambiguous, non_numeric = find_numeric(df["col"])
```

- numeric: any value interpreted as numeric by the regex
- ambiguous: numeric values with non-numeric at front or end (e.g.
  "$50")
- non_numeric: values that are neither numeric nor ambiguous

Check out the docs for more info: https://pypi.org/project/DataGlitch/

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @k-michael-aye 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49124057/4776227), I wrote a simple function that:

1. Detect the **column** with changed dtype
2. Extract the **first row's dtype** and the **first changed dtype** (compare to the first row).
3. Store **changed_dtypes** to a dict in the following structure:

   ```
   {
       changed_dtype_column_1: (first_row_dtype, first_changed_dtype),
       changed_dtype_column_2: (first_row_dtype, first_changed_dtype)
   }
   ```

**Code**

```py
import pandas as pd

def check_changed_dtypes(df: pd.DataFrame) -> dict:
    """
    Check for changed dtypes in a DataFrame
    """
    _df = df.copy(deep=True)

    changed_dtypes: dict = {}
    for column in _df.columns:
        column_firstrow_dtype: pd.Series = _df[[column]].iloc[0].apply(type)
        column_dtypes: pd.DataFrame = _df[[column]].applymap(type)

        changed_dtype: pd.Series = (column_dtypes != column_firstrow_dtype).any(axis=1)
        if len(_df[changed_dtype]) > 0:
            # Extract firstrow_dtype & first_changed_dtype
            firstrow_dtype = column_firstrow_dtype.values[0]
            first_changed_dtype_idx = _df[changed_dtype].index[0]
            first_changed_dtype_val = column_dtypes.iloc[first_changed_dtype_idx].values[0]

            # Append to changed_dtypes
            changed_dtypes[column] = (firstrow_dtype, first_changed_dtype_val)

    return changed_dtypes
```

**Screenshot**

[image: Sample]