# What if I need to get columns with mixed types?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

#### pandas: 0.23.4

According to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.errors.DtypeWarning.html), we get DtypeWarning: Columns (0) have mixed types if the data contains `int` and `str` and it is suggested to set low_memory=False, and this removes the warning. But my task is the opposite: to define columns with mixed types!

At first, I thought to parse the DtypeWarning message so that I could understand which columns has mixed type, but I encountered many difficulties that prevent me from relying on DtypeWarning:

1. If you reduce the number of lines from 300,000 to 250,000, then DtypeWarning no longer appears, but I need it for at least 100,000 lines
2. Even for 300,000 rows, the column is not always determined with mixed types, for example I modify dataframe from [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.errors.DtypeWarning.html):

#### From the docs:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': (['1'] * 100000 + ['X'] * 100000 + ['1'] * 100000), 'b': ['b'] * 300000})
df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
df2 = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
# DtypeWarning: Columns (0) have mixed types
```

#### My case:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ([1] * 10000 + ['X'] * 10000 + [1] *  10000) * 10, 'b': ['b'] * 300000})
df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
df2 = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
# No warning
```

It still has mixed types, but warning doesn't appears. And if I analyze types, all of these are `str`. Ie I can't analyze mixed types even by myself.

So, How I can get columns with mixed types? Is it possible to add the parameter  read_csv(mixed_types=True) and force the pandas not to hide mixed types for all datasets or for at least 100 000 rows? Or any ideas?

Thanks.

### Summary

It seems that pandas does not allow to know which columns have mixed types, but on the contrary hides mixed types behind the dtype `object` with `str` inside. DtypeWarning as an exception to the rule. [The link](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/13293#pullrequestreview-8216118) from @pygo answer explains the randomness of the DtypeWarning.

Comment: there is no `read_csv(mixed_types=True` i believe.

Comment: look at [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29376026/whats-a-good-strategy-to-find-mixed-types-in-pandas-columns)

Comment: try `df2 = pd.read_csv('test.csv', engine='c', dtype={'FULL': 'str', 'COUNT': 'int'}, header=1)`   i have included that in my answer.

Comment: You cannot have mixed column types. You *can* use the object dtype though.

Comment: @pygo, I have seen [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29376026/whats-a-good-strategy-to-find-mixed-types-in-pandas-columns), it doesn't decide my issue because pandas makes mixed data 'str' while read_csv() - both integers and strings determines as 'str'

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I want to learn how to define mixed types so that there are no errors with them, but the pandas defines them as 'str' for small data sets. Only for ~300 000 it show DtypeWarning. But I would like to see this warning for at least 100 000 rows. How I can force the pandas don't hide 'int' behind the 'str' ?

Comment: You **cannot** have mixed dtypes for columns

Comment: I don't say about mixed dtypes, I say about mixed types into object dtype!

Comment: will it always be an `int`? If not, do you mind changing things that would be `int` to `float`?

Comment: No, I don't. Most importantly identify that column has mixed types.

Comment: In order to better understand my task, it would be more correct to indicate `int` in data preparation (or `float`, there may be a variety of optionsr), I updated example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work both row & columns.

> low_memory : boolean, default True
>
> Internally process the file in chunks, resulting in lower memory use
>   while parsing, but possibly mixed type inference. To ensure no mixed
>   types either set False, or specify the type with the dtype parameter.
>   Note that the entire file is read into a single DataFrame regardless,
>   use the chunksize or iterator parameter to return the data in chunks.
>   (Only valid with C parser)

This is [From github page](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/13293#pullrequestreview-8216118)

> It is deterministic - types are consistently inferred based on what's
>   in the data. That said, the internal chunksize is not a fixed number
>   of rows, but instead bytes, so whether you can a mixed dtype warning
>   or not can feel a bit random.

I think you should not bother about those message as these error message is generic.

## OR

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('test.csv', engine='c', dtype={'FULL': 'str', 'COUNT': 'int'}, header=1)
```

Comment: The essence of my question is how to define a column with a mixed type on different datasets. I can not know beforehand what will be the data, so dtype={'FULL': 'str', 'COUNT': 'int'} not an option.
DtypeWarning is the only way the pandas shows such columns (I haven't find another), but not always (see reproducible example)

Comment: Thanks, [your link](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/13293#discussion_r87612627) explains the randomness of the DtypeWarning.

Comment: @OleksandrZaitsev, Glad  it helps :-)