# How to handle pandas dataframe that contains mix data type?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which contains a column having mix data type(float and string),because it contains mixed data types while performing merge and applying join on this column gives me NaN which shouldn't be the case. Eg. below dataframe upon

```
df.dtypes()
```

returns *dtype: object*, but when digging more deep I found there is one string value out of rest float values

```
<class 'float'>    47
<class 'str'>       1
Name: BenchMarkID, dtype: object
```

Sample data

[image]

Here 1.14 represent str type.
Is there any clean way of converting that single string value to float?

Comment: df.astype(float)?

Comment: Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29376026/find-mixed-types-in-pandas-columns) for your issue.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but this does not solve my issue. @sitharthan

Comment: @Sam Assuming that your code contains the import `import numpy as np` have you tried `df['BenchMarkID'] = df['BenchMarkID'].astype(np.float64)`? Basically ensures that all values in the target column are stored as type `numpy.float64`.

Comment: if `astype` doesn't work, `apply(float)` should. you'll have to actually do `df['BenchmarkID'] = df['BenchmarkID'].apply(float)`....

Answer (score 0):

The pandas `to_numeric()` function may help you here:

```
df['BenchmarkID'] = pandas.to_numeric(df['BenchmarkID'], errors='coerce')
```